# Is it possible to convert .qna files to other acceptable formats for the Language Studio?

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker, language-studio

In the past months/years i was working with The QnA Maker Service and did my QnA-Backups automaticlly with the .qna file format.

Now i want to migrate to migrate to the Language Studio and for i was wondering if the Language Studio does accept .qna files or is there a possible way to **convert these .qna files to a acceptable file format** for the Language Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Cognitive Service for Language docs have some information on [migrating from QnA to CQA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/migrate-qnamaker-to-question-answering).